# Url rewrite not working properly on apache 1.3

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, pcre, apache-1.3

I have this rule in .htaccess which works well on apache 2.0 and above but not with apache 1.3, please let me know how do I make it work with apache 1.3.x

```
RewriteRule ^webmaster/([^/]*)/?$ webmaster.php?section=$1 [L]
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok can you try this line:

```
RewriteRule ^webmaster/([^/]*) /webmaster.php?section=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: @anubhava thank you for the reply the rule didn't work it is still the same.

Comment: Pls provide more details so you can be helped :) Like what was the URI you tried? Is your .htaccess even enabled? What do your access and error log show?

Comment: Well there isn't any errors in the log files and the loaded modules in phpinfo() shows that mod_rewrite is enabled, I can see the url rewrite is working fine as i have other rules as well but the only problem is it is not getting the value for $_GET variables. Can I send you the link in a pm or email please? Thank You

Comment: Hello, I found out that the webmaster word in the url was not working well with the site, I just changed it to webpanel and everything is working fine, is there any reason why it is doing that please?

Comment: If `webpanel` works fine and `webmaster` doesn't work then it might be a case of some conflicting rule or code on your side. Also if you think answer was anyway helpful can you please mark it as accepted, thanks.